# How can I stop this teletype animation after its first iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am doing a typewriting effect using jquery and found this code and edited it to work perfectly as i need.

But, i have a problem that i am not able to stop the loop.

I tried to detect that the last paragraph is printed so i can add a function after that with no luck.

Your advices and hints are appreciated.

The code is:

http://jsbin.com/araget/33/

```
(function ($) {

  function typeString($target, str, cursor, delay, cb) {
    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      return html + str[cursor];
    });

    if (cursor < str.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  function deleteString($target, delay, cb) {
    var length;

    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      length = html.length;
      return html.substr(0, length - 1);
    });

    if (length > 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        deleteString($target, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // jQuery hook
  $.fn.extend({
    teletype: function (opts) {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.teletype.defaults, opts);

      return $(this).each(function () {
        (function loop($tar, idx) {
          // type
          typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {
            // delete
            setTimeout(function () {
              deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {
                loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
              });
            }, settings.pause);
          });

        }($(this), 0));
      });
    }
  });

  // plugin defaults  
  $.extend({
    teletype: {
      defaults: {
        delay: 100,
        pause: 5000,
        text: []
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
    'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
    'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et'
  ]
});

$('#cursor').teletype({
  text: ['_', ' '],
  delay: 0,
  pause: 500
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get handler from `setTimeout()` and run `clearTimeout()` with the handler.

```
var handler = setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
....
clearTimeout(handler);
```

Edit: I modified your code to explain where you should put a stop routine.

Check this link: http://jsbin.com/enukit/1

You need to clean your logic little more. Cursor should be separated or set by option, because you meant to stop the loop, which is used to blink cursor.

```
(function ($) {
  // writes the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param String str
  // @param Numeric cursor
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void

  var handler1, mycount=0, handler2, handler3;
  function typeString($target, str, cursor, delay, cb) {
    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      return html + str[cursor];
    });
    //alert('cursor:'+cursor);
    //alert('str.length:'+str);
    if (cursor < str.length - 1) {
      handler1 = setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // clears the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function deleteString($target, delay, cb) {
    var length;

    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      length = html.length;
      return html.substr(0, length - 1);
    });

    if (length > 1) {
      handler2 = setTimeout(function () {
        deleteString($target, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // jQuery hook
  $.fn.extend({
    teletype: function (opts) {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.teletype.defaults, opts);
      $(this).each(function () {
mycount=0;
        (function loop($tar, idx) {
        mycount ++;
          // type
          typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {
            // delete
            clearTimeout(handler1);
            handler3 = setTimeout(function () {
              deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {
                if (mycount<settings.text.length) {
                  loop($tar, (idx + 1));} else {
clearTimeout(handler3);
                    alert('The end!');
                  }
              });
            }, settings.pause);
          });

        }($(this), 0));
      });

    }
  });

  // plugin defaults  
  $.extend({
    teletype: {
      defaults: {
        delay: 100,
        pause: 5000,
        text: []
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
    'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
    'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et'
  ]
});
/*
$('#cursor').teletype({
  text: ['_', ' '],
  delay: 0,
  pause: 500
});
*/
```

Comment: can you alert any text after the last message printed without looping? feel free to edit my code as i am newbie to jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to stop the looping of the animation and another one to be set as a callback to be called at the end of the animation. Let's say `forever` and `end` respectively.

```
// plugin defaults  
$.extend({
  teletype: {
    defaults: {
      delay: 100,
      pause: 5000,
      text: [],
      forever: true,
      end: $.noop
    }
  }
});
```

Setting `forever` to `true` will make the animation go on indefinitely and restarting from the first element of `text` after the last one has been reached. Setting `forever` to `false` will make it stop after the first iteration has been reached.

Set `end` to a callback function that will be called upon the first iteration of the animation is done. This option requires `forever` set to `false`, otherwise it will never be called.

Use:

```
if (settings.forever || (idx + 1 < settings.text.length)) {
  loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
} else {
  settings.end.call(self);
}
```

instead of

```
loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
```

With these changes applied you can call `teletype` with the proper parameters.

```
$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,',
    'sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore',
    'magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et'
  ],
  forever: false,
  end: function(){
    alert("Teletype is done!");
  }
});
```

[You can see it here.](http://jsbin.com/araget/36/)