# Append white space

Tags: javascript

Am trying to periodically append char in a string to a div using setTimeout(),but it doesn't append the white spaces.

Here's the code

```
function animate(){
  for(let i=0; i<cipher.length; i++){
       setTimeout(()=>{
         ciphered.innerText += cipher.charAt(i)
       }, i*30)
  }
}
```

for example let's say the string is `hey you` I get `heyyou` instead.
Pls is there a way to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: By default html ignores "useless" whitespace. Try adding the css property `white-space: pre;` to your  `ciphered` element ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).

Comment: TLDR replace [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) with [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)

Comment: also: [typing animated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014066/typing-animated-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textContent`. Here's an example based on your code (somewhat modified).

```js
animate(`Hello world`, 0.2);

function animate(cipher, speed = 0.1){
  const letter = cipher[0];
  cipher = cipher.slice(1);
  document.querySelector(`#ciphered`).textContent += letter;
  if (cipher.length) {
    setTimeout(() => animate(cipher, speed), speed * 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ciphered"></div>
```